# MongoError: server ds00000-a.mongolab.com:00000 sockets closed

Tags: mongodb, post, mlab

```
{ [MongoError: server ds00000-a.mongolab.com:00000 sockets closed]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'server ds00000-a.mongolab.com:000000 sockets closed' }
```

Hi,

How do I solve this error ? I use mongolabs. The connection looks fine because it returns a ping command and also when I connect to it from mongo shell. My node application however gives the following error when I try to 'post' to the database.

server.js

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db("mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@ds00000.mongolab.com:0000/col1", {native_parser:true});

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});

 app.post('/',function(req,res){
       data2= { "name":"test",
               "email": "test",
               "number":"test",
               "message":"test"
              };
            db.collection('messages').insert(data2,function(err,result){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else{

                    console.log('insertion success');
                }

            });

             db.close();
            console.log('Connection with MongoDB is terminated');
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Replace the domain name with ip address and give a try!  It could be an issue of DNS

Comment: If you suggested  "var db = mongo.db("mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@ds********.54.235.215.124:******/col1", {native_parser:true});", then I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you behind proxies??  I mean trying to connect to mongolabs from your organization.

Comment: @harshavmb  No. My personal system connected to home wifi.

Comment: https://github.com/christkv/mongodb-core/issues/66 you might find this thread helpful. it's recommended to increase your connection timeout setting to be greater than the time it takes to run your longest-running database operation.

Comment: see also: https://github.com/christkv/mongodb-core/issues/60